# Can not do get request method because data says [object object]

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to do a get request method in Vue and Express to get data based on my *v-model*.

Below is my code that tries to send data to express.

```
getResult() {
  axios
    .get(
      `${process.env.VUE_APP_API}/hospita/result/` +
        {
          hosp_name: "SAMPLE"
        }
    )
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

and here is my get request method that receives the data coming from vuejs

```
router.get('/result/', (req, res) => {
    const sql = "SELECT *  FROM \
    ND_HOSP WHERE hosp_ptype = 'h' AND hosp_name LIKE ?";
    console.log(req.body)
    myDB.query(sql, ['%' + req.body.hosp_name + '%'], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            try {
                res.send(result);
                /*  console.log(result) */
            } catch (err) {
                res.send(err)
            }
        }
    })
})
```

but it gives me error and says 
http://localhost:9002/hospita/result/[object%20Object]

Comment: You can't concatenate an object to a string. You need to send the object in the request body, not the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `getResult()` let's to change method to `post` and `+` to `,` for passing your data in `body`. You can look at this code below:

```js
getResult() {
  axios
    .post( // <= change method to post
      `${process.env.VUE_APP_API}/hospita/result/`, // change `+` with `,`
        {
          hosp_name: "SAMPLE"
        }
    )
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

After that, don't forget to change your router `method` from `get` to `post`. You can look at this code below:

```js
// change method `get` to `post`
router.post('/result/', (req, res) => {
  const sql = "SELECT *  FROM \
  ND_HOSP WHERE hosp_ptype = 'h' AND hosp_name LIKE ?";
  console.log(req.body)
  myDB.query(sql, ['%' + req.body.hosp_name + '%'], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
          res.send(err)
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
  })
})
```

**Make sure**, because we're use the `req.body`, so, don't forget to add body parser in your `server.js` or `app.js`. It's will looks like this code below:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

problem is here: res.send(**result**);

**result** is not containing json data, it is containing any other object or blank object like {}.

so first of all try to see what is inside the result using console.log().

most of the time for the such cases two functions are very useful.

```
JSON.stringify(object);
JSON.parse(strobj);
```